# Discrete math: Need help understanding these problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find a function in the list

$n^2$, 1, $n^3$, $n \log n$, $\log n$, $n^4$, $2^n$, $n!$, $n$, $\pi^n$, $n^5$

that has the same order as:

**(a)** $f(n) = 3n^4 + 6n^2 - 8n - 5 $
**(b)** $f(n) = 5$
**(c)** $f(n) = n + \log n$

Comment: I understand your loathing if you were confused about what was being asked.  I am trying to "understand" the problems more, not just find answers.  If only one question is asked, it can be hard to comprehend how you got to the answer.  However if multiple questions are asked, it can provide a better overall understanding of how to tackle a concept.  With no previous experience in this area, I have spent the entire week trying to get a grasp on this.

Comment: Your comment above contains information which you should include as an edit in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The function in a) is of the same order of $n^4$, the function in b) is of the same order of 1, the function in c) is of the same order of $n$. This can be seen easily by applying the definition of "has the same order". In particular, $f$ and $g$ have the same order if the limits of $f(n)/g(n)$ and $g(n)/f(n)$, for $n$ that goes to infinity, are both bounded.

Comment: You can omit "the limits of" from this definition. It is possible that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(f(n))$ even though neither $f(n)/g(n)$ nor $g(n)/f(n)$ ever converges.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. The existence of the limits is a sufficient but not necessary condition, the way I wrote could be misleading, so I replaced "that is", with "in particular".

Comment: Yes, now all is well, because the functions in question do in fact meet those particular conditions.